# Script to auto switch sheet/tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets with tabs (named as 0,1,2,3,4) that contains charts and tables.

I am trying to create an app script to switch between these tabs after some X minutes, so I can use it and display as a dynamic dashboard on my TV.

I wrote the script and it works if I run through the script editor. I also created a timer trigger to call this function, however this trigger is failing to work. Does anyone have any clue?

```
function switchTabs() {

  var sheet_number = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  var next_sheet_number = parseInt(sheet_number) + 1;
  if(next_sheet_number>4){ next_sheet_number = 0; }
  var activate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(next_sheet_number).activate();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A Sheet Show**

Here's a script that creates a sheet show which is like a slide show only with sheets instead of slides.  The sidebar allows you to set the time between sheets. In your case your can just use two sheets and you'll have your required toggle.

codes.gs:

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('G+ Script Problems')
      .addItem('showSheets', 'showSheet')
      .addItem('Sheet Show Sidebar', 'SheetShowSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}
```

SheetShowDialog.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <style>
      #my_block{border:2px solid black;background-color:rgba(0,150,255,0.2);padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
      #conv_block{border: 1px solid black;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
      .bttn_block{padding:5px 5px 0px 0px;}
      .sndr_block {border:1px solid rgba(0,150,0,0.5);background-color:rgba(150,150,0,0.2);margin-bottom:2px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <div id="my_block" class="block form-group">
      <div class="sndr_block">
        <strong>Show Info:</strong>
        <br />Sheets in Show:
        <br /><div id="shtsinfo1"><input id="txt1" type="text" size="4" class="action"/></div>
        <br />Sheet Name:
        <br /><input id="txt4" type="text" size="20" class="action"/>
        <br />Sheet Number:
        <br /><input id="txt3" type="text" size="4" class="action"/>
        <br />Sheet Delay(seconds):
        <br /><input id="txt2" type="text" size="4" class="action"/>
        <select id="sel1" onChange="loadTxt('sel1','txt2');">
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10" selected>10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="35">35</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="45">45</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
        <br /><strong>Timer Controls</strong>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Start" name="startShow" id="startShow" onClick="startmytimer();" class="red" /></div>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Stop" name="stopTimer" id="stopTimer" class="red" /></div>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Step" name="step1" id="step1" onClick="mystep(0);" class="action" /></div>
      </div>
      <div id="btn-bar">
        <br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" class="green" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    var idx=1;
    var myInterval='';
      $(function() {
        $('#startTimer').click(startmytimer);
        $('#stopTimer').click(stopTimer);
        $('#txt4').val('');
        $('#txt3').val('');
        $('#txt2').val(10);
        $('#txt1').val(5);
        google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(setTotal)
           .getTotalSheets();
      });

      function showSheet()
      {
        var maxidx = $('#txt1').val();
        if(idx>maxidx)idx=1;
        if(idx<=maxidx && idx>0)
        {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(showStatus)
            .showSheet(idx);     
          idx += 1;
        }
      }

      function showStatus(r)   
      {
        if(r[0]>-1)
        {
          $('#txt3').val(r[0]);
          $('#txt4').val(r[1]);
        }
        else
        {
          $('#txt3').val('');
          $('#txt4').val(r[1]);
        }
      }

      function startmytimer()
      {
        showSheet();
        myInterval=setInterval(showSheet, Number($('#txt2').val())*1000);
        google.script.run.displayToast('Timer Started','Script Status', 5);
      }

      function stopTimer()
      {
        if(myInterval)
        {
          clearInterval(myInterval);
          google.script.run.displayToast('Timer Stopped','Script Status', 5);
        }
        else
        {
          google.script.run.displayToast('myInterval not set.','Script Status', 5);
        }
      }

      function loadTxt(from,to)
      {

          document.getElementById(to).value = document.getElementById(from).value;
      }

      function mystep(d)
      {
        idx+=d;
        showSheet();
      }

      function setTotal(n)
      {
        var s = '<select id="sel2" onChange="loadTxt(\'sel2\',\'txt1\');">';
        var n = (typeof(n)!='undefined')?n:0;
        var sel = $('#txt1').val();
        if(n>0)
        {

          for(var i=1;i<=n;i++)
          {
             var sltd = (i!=sel)?'':' selected'; 
             s+='<option value="' + i + '"' + sltd + '>' + i + '</option>';
          }
          s+='</select>';
          var el = document.getElementById('shtsinfo1').innerHTML += s;
          $('#txt1').val(sel);
        }
      }

     console.log('My Code');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

SheetShow.gs:

```
function showSheet(idx)
{
  var idx = (typeof(idx)!='undefined')?idx:1;
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  if(idx>0 && idx<=sheets.length)
  {
    var sht=sheets[idx-1];
    sht.activate();
    var r = [idx,sht.getName()];
    return r;
  }
  else
  {
    var r = [-1,'Index out of range.'];
    return r;
  }
}

function SheetShowSidebar()
{
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SheetShowDialog').setTitle('Sheet Show Info:');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function displayToast(msg,title,timeoutSeconds)
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(msg, title, timeoutSeconds)
}

function getTotalSheets()
{
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().length;
}
```

Comment: I have found it to be a very useful litttle tool in making training videos. [Here's one that I did for my website](https://youtu.be/iZ64eT1c3zg).

Answer (score -1):

I like Cooper's answer, but couldn't find a way to hide the sidebar while keeping the sheet show going. I'm using a Chrome Cast to display a sheet on a TV, so the sidebar was visible on the TV too. Another solution I found that works better for my case is a Chrome add-in that cycles through tabs on a set interval. I open the Google Sheet in multiple Chrome tabs with each tab showing a different sheet and the add-in cycles between them.

The add-in I found to work best is [Tabs SlideShow by FredZvt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-slideshow-by-fredzvt/iblklbkhojnomhjkgjfooemifbgibmho/related?hl=en). This one only cycles tabs in the window it's run in and doesn't affect other Chrome windows, you can set time spent on each tab independently or exclude specific tabs, and it can auto-reload specific tabs each time it shows them.