# Script to sheetshow google sheets tabs like a slide show, answered by cooper, but the chart tab doesn't show

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This query is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554184/script-to-auto-switch-sheet-tabs/56554417#56554417?newreg=1250ff84348f4c31b393f2e10a6a9749)

and is answered beautifully by Cooper, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554417/20051040)

But I have an issue where there's a tab on my sheet that contains a chart (created by moving a chart into its own tab), and that tab doesn't show, even though the sidebar chooses its tab number and name, but it just stays in the tab before it until the timer is finished then it moves to the tab after it.

Do you have a fix?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your situation.  I put a chart on a sheet and it shows up just fine

Comment: The contents of the sheet have nothing to do with the operation of the script

Comment: I completely understand, but it just skips the chart, and only the chart, even though it shows its number in the sidebar, I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sTd6CjedZN_QwwGbumnyAbFBMjBbAxTpK9xdY5mc9UY/edit?usp=sharing